# Determining with C# Whether a SQL Backup File is Password Protected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2000, password-protection

How would I go about using C# to programmatically determine whether a SQL Server 2000 backup file has been password protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native password protection for SQL Server backup files.  So I'd recommend something like this:

```
IF (1==1)
{
//It's not password protected
}
```

Just kidding.  Which application are you using the "Password Protect" the backup files?  You'll likely have to contact the application vendor.

Comment: By "password protected," I should've said that the backup was created using the "WITH PASSWORD = 'password'" parameter.  After a little bit more research I've realized that this parameter isn't actually encrypting the backup file, it's just requiring that the password be supplied any time the backup is manipulated.

Comment: To be honest, you actually threw me off with the WITH PASSWORD bit - I haven't seen the syntax in forever.  Keep in mind that it's going to be discontinued in the next version of SQL Server (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx).  I would just do a RESTORE FILELISTONLY on the file, and catch the output to determine whether it returned a filelist, or an error stating that the password needs to be supplied.

Comment: Yes I was aware that it's going to be discontinued, I just have some existing backup files that may or may not have been created with the WITH PASSWORD option. Thanks for the RESTORE FILELISTONLY suggestion, that's what I was looking for!